# AttributeError: type object 'ManagerWithFind' has no attribute 'client'

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-nova, bare-metal

I am new to python and openstack so please don't lose your cool :)

Here I am trying to instantiate BareMetalNodeManager class object (from np_orchestration.py).

**np_orchestration.py**

```
from baremetal import BareMetalNodeManager
from novaclient import base

class np_orchestration:
    def provisionNodes(self):
        obj = BareMetalNodeManager(base.ManagerWithFind);
        var =        obj.create(self,"192.168.XXX.XXX",1,514,1,"00:0C:29:XX:XX:XX","192.168.XXX.XXX","XXXX","XXXX")
        print var

obj = np_orchestration()
obj.provisionNodes()
```

This class (located in baremetal.py) requires base.ManagerWithFind as parameter (which is an abstract class)

**baremetal.py**

```
class BareMetalNodeManager(base.ManagerWithFind):
"""
Manage :class:`BareMetalNode` resources.
"""
resource_class = BareMetalNode

def create(self,
           service_host,
           cpus,
           memory_mb,
           local_gb,
           prov_mac_address,
           pm_address=None,
           pm_user=None,
           pm_password=None,
           terminal_port=None):
    """
    Create a baremetal node.

    :param service_host: Name of controlling compute host
    :param cpus: Number of CPUs in the node
    :param memory_mb: Megabytes of RAM in the node
    :param local_gb: Gigabytes of local storage in the node
    :param pm_address: Power management IP for the node
    :param pm_user: Username for the node's power management
    :param pm_password: Password for the node's power management
    :param prov_mac_address: MAC address to provision the node
    :param terminal_port: ShellInABox port
    :rtype: :class:`BareMetalNode`
    """
    body = {'node': {'service_host': service_host,
                    'cpus': cpus,
                    'memory_mb': memory_mb,
                    'local_gb': local_gb,
                    'pm_address': pm_address,
                    'pm_user': pm_user,
                    'pm_password': pm_password,
                    'prov_mac_address': prov_mac_address,
                    'terminal_port': terminal_port}}

    return self._create('/os-baremetal-nodes', body, 'node')
```

I get the following error when I try to do so:

```
farooqui@ubuntu:/projects/kenobi$ python np_orchestration.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "np_orchestration.py", line 15, in <module>
obj.provisionNodes()
File "np_orchestration.py", line 11, in provisionNodes
var = obj.create(self,"192.168.42.134",1,514,1,"00:0C:29:CF:E6:D9","192.168.42.225","admin","abc")
File "/projects/kenobi/baremetal.py", line 82, in create
return self._create('/os-baremetal-nodes', body, 'node')
File "/opt/stack/python-novaclient/novaclient/base.py", line 100, in _create
_resp, body = self.api.client.post(url, body=body)
AttributeError: type object 'ManagerWithFind' has no attribute 'client'
farooqui@ubuntu:/projects/kenobi$
```

full version of baremetal.py can be found here:
https://github.com/openstack/python-novaclient/blob/master/novaclient/v1_1/contrib/baremetal.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
from baremetal import BareMetalNodeManager
from novaclient import base, client
import os

config_file = open('config.json')
config_data = json.load(config_file)

class np_orchestration:

    def __init__(self):
        self.os_auth_url = config_data["config"]["OS_AUTH_URL"]
        self.os_username = config_data["config"]["OS_USER"]
        self.os_password = config_data["config"]["OS_PASSWORD"]
        self.os_tenant_name = config_data["config"]["OS_TENANT_NAME"]
        self.os_tenant_id = config_data["config"]["OS_TENANT_ID"]
        self.client = client._construct_http_client(self.os_username, self.os_password, project_id=None,
                           auth_url= self.os_auth_url, endpoint_type='publicURL',
                           service_type='compute',
                           auth_system='keystone', auth_plugin=None,
                           auth_token=None, cacert=None, tenant_id= self.os_tenant_id)

     def provisionNodes(self):
        obj = BareMetalNodeManager(self);
        var = obj.create(self,"192.168.XXX.XXX",1,514,1,"00:0C:29:XX:XX:XX","192.168.XXX.XXX","XXXX","XXXX")
        print var

obj = np_orchestration()
obj.provisionNodes()
```

Comment: Thanks. For future reference, the newest novaclient expects client.HTTPClient instead of the _construct_http_client(), and also for project_id=None to be passed as projectid=None